# Indeterminate forms: Usual and unusual

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, indeterminate-forms

What are indeterminate forms? And how are some usual and unusual? I know that indeterminate forms can be the ratio of two functions where the functions have a zero limit tendency, but I do not fully understand the concept.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: The form (not expression) $a\circ b$ where $a,b$ are in the extended reals and $\circ$ is an algebraic operation ($+,-,\cdot, /$ or exponentiation) is indeterminate if knowing only that $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ does not tell you much about the limit behaviour of $a_n\circ b_n$ as $n\to \infty$. This *may* be caused from $a\circ b$ not being defined / consistently definable, but it *may* also be caused by a discontinuity of $\circ$ at that point ...